# Rails route that has the url that points to a different model object every day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

So I was trying to do something where if I go to `/daily_products` then it would 
show a new product page where user can submit a new review each day.

Currently I have a mapping `product/:id/review/new` to `review#new`. I was wondering if I could something like `/daily_products` to map to a `product/:id/review/new/` with `:id` being different each day. Does anyone know how to do this in Rails route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest another approach:

In your **routes** file:

```
get 'daily_products', to: 'products#daily'
```

And in your **Products controller** you could have the action daily as:

```
def daily
  @daily_product = Product.daily
  render '/review/new/' # I am not sure where you have the actual review template...
end
```

Then in your **Product model**, you define the daily scope at your own taste. For example, selecting a random Product every day:

```
def self.daily
  if (c = count) != 0
    find(:first, :offset =>rand(c))
  end
end
```

Notice that this will give a random Product for each User. There is not any kind of cache of what is a daily product across all the users. You can easily do that though. The idea is isolating the concept of daily in the Model, not in the routes.